# How to redirect in Angular2 on receiving success status?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I don't want to use `location.href` which actually loads/refreshes and redirects to the url. I want same page loading (don't know if that is the actual term), ie. the page to open without reloading or refreshing the browser.

Here are the routes that are defined in my **app.module.ts**.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
          { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
          { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

Here is the submit function defined in my **login.component.ts**.

```
submitPost()
{        
    this._adminLogin.postAdminLogin(this.adminLoginmodel).subscribe(
        data => {
              this.responseStatus = data;
              if(this.responseStatus.status.length > 0 && this.responseStatus.status == 1)
              {
                alert('Login Success');
              }
              else
              {
                alert('Login Error');
              }
            },
        err => {
              console.log(err)
            },
        () => {}
    ); 
    this.status = true;       
}
```

How can I do this?

EDIT:

Thanks to people for their suggestions in the answer section. However, `router.navigate('admin/dashboard')` is throwing me an error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: router is not defined
Stack trace:
LoginComponent.prototype.submitPost/<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/admin/login/login.component.ts:32:17
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:245:13
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:192:17
```

But I have added imported `Router` in my login.component from before. Here is my total code in login.component.ts:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { fadeInAnimation } from '../../_animations/index';
import { Admin } from '../../_models/admin.model';
import { AdminLoginService } from '../../_admin_service/admin.login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  animations: [fadeInAnimation],
  host: { '[@fadeInAnimation]': '' },
  providers: [AdminLoginService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    responseStatus:Object= [];
    status:boolean ;
    //@Input() admin:Admin;

  adminLoginmodel = new Admin('', '', '', 'Emailsss','Passwordsss');    

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private _adminLogin: AdminLoginService
    ){}

    submitPost()
  {        
      this._adminLogin.postAdminLogin(this.adminLoginmodel).subscribe(
          data => {
                this.responseStatus = data;
                if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
                {
                  this.router.navigate('admin/dashboard')
                }
                else
                {
                  alert('Login Error');
                }
              },
          err => {
                console.log(err)
              },
          () => {}
      ); 
      this.status = true;       
  }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Are you loooking for `router.navigate('admin/dashboard')`?

Comment: Putting this line gives `router is not defined` error in console.

Comment: You have to inject it in your constructor: constructor(private router: Router) {}

Comment: Here is a simple example of routing in angular : https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplest-routing-example

Comment: I just edited my answer : you have to use your class to access your router as the way you inject it make it a class variable :)

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/Router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the angular `router` into your component and then call `navigate`.

```
    export class MyClass {
      constructor(private router: Router) {}

      submitPost() {        
          this._adminLogin.postAdminLogin(this.adminLoginmodel).subscribe(
            data => {
              this.responseStatus = data;
              if(this.responseStatus.status.length > 0 && this.responseStatus.status === 1)
              {
                  this.router.navigate(['/successUrl']);
              }
              else
              {
                  this.router.navigate(['/errorUrl']);
              }
            },
        err => {
              console.log(err)
            },
        () => {}
    ); 
    this.status = true;       
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps. You just have to pass a arry to router.navigate method.

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  @Injectable()
  export class ErrorHandlerService {
      constructor(private router: Router) {}

      public handleError(): void {
          this.router.navigate(['/your-redirect-path']).catch(() => {
               console.log('Navigation Failure');
          });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) in your component and use it to redirect your user to where you want without having to perform a complete reload of your app like with location.href.

For example, i you have a "success" route to redirect your use in case of success, and otherwise a "fail" route, it would looks like something like that :

```
constructor (private router: Router) {}

submitPost () {
    this._adminLogin.postAdminLogin(this.adminLoginmodel).subscribe(
       data => {
            // Do your stuff in case of success
            this.router.navigate(['success']);
       },
       err => {
            // Do your stuff in case of failure
            this.router.navigate(['fail']);
       }
}
```

Be careful, this way your router is accessible thanks to your class, so you have to use :

```
this.router.navigate
```

and not

```
router.navigate
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Angular Router by injecting it into login.component.ts

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router){}
```

and in your 'Login Success'

```
this.router.navigate('dashboard');
```